# Draw a path progressively with getSegment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin, android-canvas

I created a custom view to draw a line, but progressively. I tried to use PathMeasure and getSegment, but the effect doesn't work. It just keeps drawing the line already with the final size.

```
private val paint = Paint().apply {
    isAntiAlias = true
    color = Color.WHITE
    style = Paint.Style.STROKE
    strokeWidth = 10f
}


override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)

    val path = Path().apply {
        moveTo(width/2.toFloat(), height/2.toFloat())
        lineTo(width/2.toFloat(), height/4.toFloat())
    }

    val measure = PathMeasure(path, false)
    val length = measure.length
    val partialPath = Path()
    measure.getSegment(0.0f, length, partialPath, true)
    partialPath.rLineTo(0.0f, 0.0f)
    canvas!!.drawPath(partialPath, paint)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this with DashPathEffect

```
DashPathEffect dashPathEffect = new DashPathEffect(new float[]{1000.0f,9999999},0);
Paint.setPathEffect(dashPathEffect);
```

change 1000 to your length ("on" parts in Dash)

and set 99999999 to your max ("off" parts in Dash)

play with this parameters and read this [article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/playing-with-paths-3fbc679a6f77) please

[image]

Comment: Thank u! I made it with ValueAnimator and DashPathEffect

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I made it, as @mohandes explained:

```
private var path = Path()
private var paint = Paint()
private val dashes = floatArrayOf(125f, 125f)

init {

    paint = Paint().apply {
        isAntiAlias = true
        color = Color.WHITE
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        strokeWidth = 10.0f
        pathEffect = CornerPathEffect(8f)
    }

    path = Path().apply {
        moveTo(312f, 475f)
        lineTo(312f, 375f)
    }


    val lineAnim = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(100f, 0f)
    lineAnim.interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
    lineAnim.addUpdateListener {
        paint.pathEffect = ComposePathEffect(DashPathEffect(dashes, lineAnim.animatedValue as Float), CornerPathEffect(8f))
        invalidate()
    }

    lineAnim.duration = 1000
    lineAnim.start()
}

override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    canvas!!.drawPath(path, paint)
}
```